# Are there any outposts that provide +2 or more of X resources?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

I am trying to be efficient with my upgrades, making sure that I am limiting the amount of resources I am using per day on specific base upgrades by supplementing them with outposts with resource bonuses.

Are there any outposts that have more than +1 bonus resource per day(ammo/ meds/ building materials/ etc) ?

I want to upgrade my base and try to limit the bleeding of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are not, there are only outposts that provide:

- +1 of any resource
- +2 beds
- Water
- Power (electricity)
- Artilliry strikes (not as good as SoD 1)
- Signal boost (reduces radio calls cooldown)

---

It is perfectly possible to balance an entire base to provide +0 or even +1 of each resource per day.

One of the biggest requirements to achieve this is to complete the Builder Legacy and use its perk in a new playthrough, this will provide all your bases with free water and power. This will save you a slot on your base and/or 1-2 outpost slots (not to mention a bucketload of influence).

The second thing you will need is to max out your outposts to 6 slots, do this by upgrading your Command Center to level 3 to get 4 outpost slots and installing the facility mod that gives you another +2 outposts.

The third tip is to choose your survivors carefully. Some survivors have a Hero bonus that will provide +1 medicine, fuel, food,... per day. This is a good assistance to balance your costs. Some will also provide +2 beds or have traits that say they don't need a bed.

Last, choose your facilities wisely. A rank 2 Workshop with power will provide +1 material per day, so definitely upgrade this. A grade 3 Infirmary will need -1 material per day, but a grade 2 does not use up any materials and a grade 2 with a cast making kit will provide enough passive recovery to keep your community in good health, so maybe don't upgrade this until you really need too.
Same for rank 2 bed facilities, It might be better to keep them and rank 1 and sacrifice an outpost to get more beds.
Most large slot facilities will use up 1 material per day, so will the legacy buildings. But a staging area will neutralize all material costs for upkeep.
Install a Compost Bin at a Garden or Farm to double your food production.

Comment: Really really good input, thank you for this! +1 & ✔

Comment: what is the facility mod called that adds two outposts from the command center?

Comment: @ZeroStack Network Signal Booster
Purchased from Network Trader. Attach to Command Center tier 2 or higher to unlock 2 more Outpost slots.